# POST to ASP.NET Web Service with iOS

Tags: asp.net, ios

I have set up a ASP.NET Web service that I have tested on the server through the auto-generated service webpage.

But I can't post data to it correctly by an iOS app.  **I'm getting no errors but its also not ever firing the method of the web service.

Please help..

```
NSURL *siteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server/.../IOSDataWebService/Service1.asmx?op=testMethod"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:siteURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
NSString *postString = @"fieldToAdd=TestString";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:postString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or response. This is a pretty vague question

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that.. I don't get any errors from the iOS app and also nothing shows in the event viewer on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `postString.length`, instead of `postString` itself, as the value of the `Content-Length` header.

Oh, wait, you can't set just a bare integer there. Let's try wrapping it as a `NSNumber` instead with `@(postString.length)`.